# Why Does HashTable still in existence in Java, when ConcurrentHashMap is more efficient than it?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, hashtable, concurrenthashmap

As far as I know ConcurrentHashMap partitions the buckets and has **separate locks on each partition**. But the HashTable has one **single lock** for all buckets.

As a result the ConcurrentHashMap can be either more efficient or (in worst case )equally efficient as HashTable. So why does Java needs to keep HashTable in its latest versions.

**Isn't HashTable obselete now? Or are there still some pros HashTable has over ConcurrentHashMap?**

Comment: "*So why does Java needs to keep HashTable in its latest versions*" because for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple reason: there might be zillions of lines of code using that classic. And people that would like to recompile that code using a newer JDK.

You want to break all of them!?

Comment: On the other hand, Oracle broke applets many times before, by moving the security baseline that requires new entries in manifest. Clients update their JRE and you get a call in the middle of the night.

Comment: The fact that Sun/Oracle makes one decision one day doesn't mean that they will not make other decisions on other days ;-)

Comment: Also, `Properties extends Hashtable`. So actually we're merrily using it everywhere.

Comment: Of course, theoretically one could even think about keeping the Hashtable interface, but completely rework its inner implementation; but that might cause strange effects here or there; and thus: also not a really good idea!

Comment: You can not rework the internals of `Hashtable` to be like `ConcurrentHashMap`. It’s a crucial part of its design that it *does* use `synchronized`, which implies that client code may use `synchronized` too, to perform a multi-step update with the guaranty that all other concurrent accesses get blocked. Such code can not get redirected to use `ConcurrentHashMap` at all; it would require an entirely different algorithm then. We can not even assume that every use case has a lock free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This concept is NOT only applicable for `Hashtable`, in fact it is applicable for all legacy classes, as Java versions are expected to be binary backwards-compatible.

This will be really helpful for the applications or projects **wanted to upgrade to the newer versions of Java without worrying about modifying their existing functionality**, which use some legacy classes (like `Hashtable`, `Vector`, etc..).

**Backward Compatibility**

> Java versions are expected to be binary backwards-compatible. For
>   example, JDK 8 can run code compiled by JDK 7 or JDK 6. It is common
>   to see applications leverage this backwards compatibility by using
>   components built by different Java version. A Compatibility Guide
>   (explained later) exists for each major release to provide special
>   mention when something is not backwards compatible.

You can look at [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upgrading_major_java_versions)